# Add new child in TreeView from TextBox in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, treeview

I have use the code below. And this tables in my database. I have textbox and button and i want on button click to be possible to add new child on Proba1,Proba2...What change i need to make and write in my code:

[image]
[image]

Output display:

[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    fill_Tree2();

}


void fill_Tree2()
{



    DataSet PrSet = PDataset("Select * from ParentTable");

    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();

    foreach (DataRow dr in PrSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {

        TreeNode tnParent = new TreeNode();

        tnParent.Text = dr["ParentName"].ToString();

        tnParent.Value = dr["ParentID"].ToString();

        tnParent.PopulateOnDemand = true;

        tnParent.ToolTip = "Click to get Child";

        tnParent.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;

        tnParent.Expand();

        tnParent.Selected = true;

        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tnParent);

        FillChild(tnParent, tnParent.Value);

    }



}

public void FillChild(TreeNode parent, string ParentId)
{

    DataSet ds = PDataset("Select * from ChildTable where ParentId =" + ParentId);

    parent.ChildNodes.Clear();

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {

        TreeNode child = new TreeNode();

        child.Text = dr["ChildName"].ToString().Trim();

        child.Value = dr["ChildId"].ToString().Trim();

        if (child.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
        {

            child.PopulateOnDemand = true;

        }

        child.ToolTip = "Click to get Child";

        child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;

        child.CollapseAll();

        parent.ChildNodes.Add(child);

    }

}



protected DataSet PDataset(string Select_Statement)
{

    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cms;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(Select_Statement, SqlCon);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ad.Fill(ds);

    return ds;



}
```